# Warum heißt der "Hundegang" so?

Tags: etymology

*Hundegang* ist ein Begriff, der eine besondere Fortbewegungsweise eines zweispurigen Fahrzeugs mit mehreren lenkbaren Achsen bezeichnet, bei dem die Bewegungsrichtung des Fahrzeugs nicht entlang der Längsachse geschieht - Vorder- und Hinterachsen laufen dabei versetzt zueinander.

[image]

Die Bezeichnung für diese Fortbewegungsart ist anscheinend nach dem Gang von Hunden gewählt - nur: Meine Hunde haben sich nie so bewegt, im Prinzip *könnten* sich aber wohl alle Vierbeiner auf so eine Art bewegen.

Beim Dressurreiten gibt es eine ähnliche Fortbewegungsart: *das Traversieren*, bei dem sich das Pferd diagonal zu seiner Längsachse fortbewegt. Das war aber anscheinend nicht Vorbild genug für die Wahl des Begriffs.

Im Englischen heißt diese Technik bei Maschinen *crab steering*, im Französischen übereinstimmend *marche en crabe* - Nach der Krabbe, die aber im Deutschen eher als **komplett seitwärts gehend** angesehen wird, was die meisten dieser Fahrzeuge aber nicht können. Tatsächlich habe ich keine Sprache außer der deutschen gefunden, die diese Bewegung mit dem Hund assoziiert.

Meine Frage: Woher kommt diese Bezeichnung, kann möglicherweise jemand die erste Verwendung des Begriffs finden und warum hat man im Deutschen von allen Tieren ausgerechnet den Hund genommen, um diese Bewegung zu bezeichnen, von dem ich finde, dass das keine seiner typischen Bewegungsarten ist (Ich hätte das Pferd viel naheliegender gefunden, zumal es dort schon einen passenden Begriff gab)?

Noch eine Anmerkung: Der finnsche Traktorhersteller Valtra verwendet für seine Traktoren, die eine ähnliche Bewegung ausführen können (auch wenn sie dabei die Hinterräder nicht lenken, sondern den Traktor dazu in der Mitte "knicken"), den englischen Begriff *dog walk*. Kann hier jemand Finnisch und weiß, wie das auf Finnisch heißt? Es ist die einzige Erwähnung eines Hundes außerhalb der deutschen Sprache für diese Technik, die ich finden konnte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bei Google Books](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22hundegang%22&tbas=0&biw=1680&bih=917&source=lnt&tbs=sbd%3A1%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1920%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1965&tbm=bks) sieht es so aus, als ob der Begriff zu Beginn der 60er Jahre des 20. Jahrhunderts zum ersten Mal für diese Art der Lenkung benutzt wurde. Soweit die Fundstellen den Begriff erläutern, beziehen sie sich alle auf das Fahren mit versetzten Spuren, d.h. die Hinterräder laufen nicht in der Spur der Vorderräder, was bei Geradeausfahrt z.B. den Vorteil einer geringeren Bodenbelastung bringen kann (um den Preis einer größeren überfahrenen Fläche).

Wie Christian in seiner Antwort schon geschrieben hat, soll dieses Laufbild bei Hunden recht häufig vorkommen. Eine "enzyklopädische" Referenz dazu habe ich nicht gefunden (und bin selbst auch kein Hundefachmann), aber viele Forumsdiskussionen. Siehe dazu exemplarisch [diesen Thread bei gutefrage.net](https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/hunde-laufen-schief-warum) und [diese Diskussion zum Nutzen der Hundeganglenkung](https://www.landtreff.de/was-bringt-mir-der-hundegang-t10334.html), in der ausdrücklich der Bezug zu den leicht schräg laufenden Hunden hergestellt wird. Oft wird angemerkt, dass sich die Hunde sonst selbst in die Haxen  treten würden. Falls das stimmt, hätte [Takkat in seiner Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/38571/9091) gerade das falsche Beispiel gewählt, denn beim Passgang ist dieses Problem ja gerade nicht vorhanden.

Und warum nun ausgerechnet der Hund? Darüber kann ich nur spekulieren. Neben dem Pferd (und andernorts dem Kamel, das aber im Passgang läuft) ist der Hund das Lauftier, mit dem der Mensch den häufigsten Umgang hat. Pferden trainiert man diesen diagonalen Laufstil aber offenbar gezielt ab (und Traversieren ist, was die hier wesentliche Laufspur angeht, ganz was anderes), also bleibt der Hund.

Comment: Nur beim Passgang bilden die Körperachsen aus Vorderpfoten und Hinterpfoten ein Parallelogramm, stehen also **schräg** und führen dann zu dem Laufbild, welches Christian beschreibt.

Comment: @Takkat Christian beschreibt vor allem eine Körperhaltung: Schulter und Becken zur Wirbelsäule leicht gekippt (aber zueinander parallel). Damit steht die Wirbelsäule schräg zur Laufrichtung. Die Pfoten bewegen sich hingegen (bei jeder Gangart) in Laufrichtung, stehen aber nicht mehr hintereinander - genau wie bei diesen Traktoren.

Comment: Tatsächlich ist es **die** wesentliche Eigenschaft des Hundegangs, dass Vorder- und Hinterräder nicht in einer Spur laufen. Oder, gesehen an der Bewegungsrichtung, dass die eben nicht in Richtung der Längsachse des Fahrzeugs, sondern diagonal dazu stattfindet. Beides gilt auch für die Traverse beim Dressurreiten (damit widerspreche ich deinem letzten Satz, alles andere soweit prima)

Comment: @tofro Es ging mir bei dem Einschub im letzten Satz hauptsächlich um die Spuren - das sind beim Traversieren nur 3, nicht 4. Siehe http://www.pferdewissen.ch/seitengaenge1.php#trle (die gestrichelten Linien im ersten Diagramm und der letzte Satz). Außerdem sieht es zumindest dort so aus, als ob der Pferdekörper dabei leicht gebogen ist, weshalb es m.E. schwierig ist, von _einer_ Körperachse zu sprechen - auch wenn sich gerade von vorn gesehen der Eindruck ergibt, das Pferd würde diagonal laufen.

Comment: Warum auch immer das so genannt wird, es ist einfach falsch. Der Hund könnte zB nie gerade in eine Parklücke laufen, da sein Körper diagonal zum Ziel steht. Übrigens nennt man diese Gangart in den USA "crabbing". Für mich ist das ganz klar ein "Krabbengang". Egal welche Bezeichnung dafür jemand vor 100 Jahren dafür erfunden hat. Siehe auch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hExlQWS2k3Y

Comment: @mgutt Das das im Englischen (und im Französischen) "Krabbengang" heißt, stand ja schon in der Frage.

Answer (score 3):

Man sieht im Alltag bei Hunden recht häufig, dass sie etwas 'verzogen' laufen: Schultern vorne und Becken hinten stehen nicht im 90-Grad-Winkel zur Wirbelsäule (wie es ein klassisches Schönheitsideal sowie die Ergonomie wollten), sondern die Wirbelsäule steht leicht schräg zur Laufrichtung, und das Becken läuft gegenüber den Schultern etwas seitlich versetzt (parallelversetzt).

Vorderpfoten und Hinterpfoten laufen dann nicht in der gleichen Spur.

Dies alles bezeiht sich natürlich auf das Geradeauslaufen, nicht auf Kurven.

Ein Schönheitsfehler bei Hunden wie bei Fahrzeugen (es sei denn, es ist beabsichtigt).

Ich habe das Wort "Hundegang" allerdings noch nie gehört. Bin aber auch weder Fahrzeugingenieur noch Hundetrainer.

Comment: Meine französische Bulldogge läuft definitiv so, bin erleichtert, dass ich diese Frage gefunden habe und daher weiss, dass das als normal anzusehen ist.

Answer (score 1):

Eine mögliche Erklärung wäre auch, dass bei Bulldogge einem bizzaren rassenspezifischen Schönheitsidal nach, die eine Schulter (linke?) immer vor der anderen hervorstehen solle. Dies ergibt einen schrägen Eindruck, ähnlich dem vom Traktor im Bild

Comment: Wenn es *Hundestand* heißen würde, wäre das eine logische Erklärung. Es geht aber ums Gehen.

Answer (score 0):

Eine naheliegende Antwort ist: Bestimmte Hunderassen können sich mit den pfoten berühren. Beim dackel ist klar, der kann niemals im laufen seine hinterpfoten zur vorderpfoten bringen- langer körper kurze beine. wenn jetzt die Beine länger werden und der Körper kurzer, erreichen ich einen Punkt wo die Hinterpfote mit den krallen die Vorderpfoten berührt und verletzen kann.